# KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps is forced to be set to True in AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

By some reason when I try to set `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` to `false` the AWS Step Functions gives me the following error message:

```
There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue.
The value for the 'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps' field MUST be true (at /States/CreateCluster/Parameters)
```

The only explanation I can think of is that ASL forces you terminate the cluster in a separate step otherwise the State Machine may not complete.

Could somebody confirm or explain this behaviour?